# Change width of tabs in all browsers

Tags: html, css, xml, internet-explorer, width

I have a little problem. I print an XML file as a string in a textarea. But when I open the textarea in Firefox or Internet Explorer there is a huge difference between the width of the tabspaces. In Internet Explorer the tabspace has a width of approximately 10 spaces, while in FireFox and Chrome it is more like 4 spaces.

Can anyone tell me how I can set the tabspace for every browser so it all looks the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since to add xml in a textarea, you are using string,
you can convert all the tabs into spaces using javascript as follows:

```
var tab = RegExp("\\t", "g");
var new_str = str.replace(tab,"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

So that the width will remain same in any browser.